# How do you include an Oracle Client within a VB.NET app for Oracle 12c?

Tags: vb.net, oracle

How does one architect a VB.NET desktop app (no web, app server) so that it includes an Oracle Client within itself? Incorporating it as part of the build.  So that it can be distributed with having to have each desktop also install a separate Oracle Client?  (Using Oracle 12c)

(The pros and cons of this approach notwithstanding.  I don't have a choice in the matter.)

Comment: You can't. You have to build an installer that bundles the Oracle client (and means your users will likely need admin rights on their local machines to install your program). If you don't like it, take it up with Oracle and ask them to make a managed client that doesn't need to be installed.

Comment: The original ap used something called InterOp.InProcServer.dll -- I believe.  I take it more modern implementations of Oracle have no analog of this?

Comment: You could use the ODP.NET Managed Driver, then you have to provide only a single DLL `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` with your application.

Comment: Are you *absolutely certain* that Oracle license you to distribute their software in this way? (They don't even give java free nowadays...)